# Magic methods on class self

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

I am looking for a way to call magic methods on class instances. In my case, I want to call hash on class based on properties. I found solution with metaclass, but I cannot access class properties from metaclass's method.

```
class X(type):
    @classmethod
    def __hash__(cls):
        return hash(cls.x)
class Y(metaclass=X):
        x = (1, 2, 3)
assert hash(Y) == hash((1, 2, 3))
```

I found just this thread: [Defining magic methods on classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759273/defining-magic-methods-on-classes)

Comment: "but I cannot access class properties from metaclass's method" - what? Sure you can.

Comment: Why do you want to override the hashing of class objects?  You're now obliged to implement the `__eq__` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `@classmethod` off.

```
class X(type):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.x)
class Y(metaclass=X):
        x = (1, 2, 3)
assert hash(Y) == hash((1, 2, 3))
```

You want `__hash__` to receive `Y`, which is an instance of `X`. You don't want it to receive `X`.